# Help with SOQL for loop

Tags: apex, soql

Could anyone help me with the code bellow please?
MasterIdSet - may contain one or more ids
Master_ID__c -  is an external id which value could be the same across one or more Accounts.
I would expect to see 2 Account records in my map, because the Master_ID__c is populated to two accounts:

```
acctMap{144383353=(001G000006iXPV3AAO), (001G000004iXPV3AAO)}
```

but getting:

```
acctMap{144383353=(001G000006iXPV3AAO)}
```

Here is my code:

```
 Set<String> masterIdSet = new Set<String>();
    Map<String,list<id>> acctMap = new Map<String,list<id>>();
    for(Account a:[SELECT Id, Owner.Id, Owner.Name, Salesforce_Account_ID__c, Name, Status__c,Include_in_Funnel__c, Master_ID__c FROM Account WHERE Master_ID__c IN :masterIdSet]) acctMap.put(a.Master_ID__c, new list<id>{a.Id});
    System.debug('acctMap' +acctMap);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Map have unique keys, even if you have same key in loop , the latest  key will overwrite the value of the old key. You have to check if key exists, if yes add Id to the list else create a new list for the key.

```
Set<String> masterIdSet = new Set<String>();
Map<String,list<id>> acctMap = new Map<String,list<id>>();
for(Account a:[SELECT Id, Owner.Id, Owner.Name, Salesforce_Account_ID__c, Name, Status__c,
                Include_in_Funnel__c, Master_ID__c 
                FROM Account 
                WHERE Master_ID__c IN :masterIdSet]){

        if(acctMap.containsKey(a.Master_ID__c)){
            acctMap.get(a.Master_ID__c).add(a.Id);
        }else{
            acctMap.put(a.Master_ID__c, new list<id>{a.Id});
        }

}
System.debug('acctMap' +acctMap);
```

Answer (score 0):

You keep replacing the list with a new list every time

You need to see if a value exists, if it does add to it and replace the old value.

```
Set<String> masterIdSet = new Set<String>();
Map<String,list<id>> acctMap = new Map<String,list<id>>();
for(Account a:[SELECT Id, Owner.Id, Owner.Name, Salesforce_Account_ID__c, Name, Status__c,Include_in_Funnel__c, Master_ID__c FROM Account WHERE Master_ID__c IN :masterIdSet]) {
    List<Id> existingList = acctMap.get(a.Master_Id__c);
    if (existingList == null) {
        existingList = new List<Id>;
    }
    existingList.add(a.Id);
    acctMap.put(a.Master_ID__c, existingList);
}

System.debug('acctMap' +acctMap);
```